# Migrating from 2.x to 3.0 (GXT) by module

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am thinking of developing a Ext GWT "GXT" 3.0 module that I need to embed to a GXT 2.x web application. Is it a good strategy to load a GXT module in a iframe. I mean, so I can develop the new module using GXT 3 and still "embed" the module in a GXT 2.x based web application. The application is quite big, so I don't think that there will be anyone in the project team that will be able to adapt to 3.0 just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to run them together in the same project thanks to them using a different namespace.

http://www.sencha.com/learn/running-ext-gwt-2-and-3-together/

Also if you plan to convert your older GXT2.x modules to GXT3 there is a legacy module to help with the transition. See :
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?197973-How-to-use-the-Legacy-module&p=787639&viewfull=1#post787639